# Why don't using two loops slow down the program?

Tags: python-3.x, performance, nested-for-loop

So I have these two loops, and I noticed that their runtime is almost the same.
Can someone explain why is this the case if the one has one more inner loop in it?

I am using this file: https://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox.txt

```
import time

def weekday():
    inp = input("Filename: ")
    fhand = open(inp)
    flist = list()
    fdict = dict()
    start_time = time.time()
    for line in fhand:
        line = line.rstrip() #remove \n in the right
        if not line.startswith("From "):
            continue #finds line starting with From and then find next one
        words = line.split() #create list of words in the line
        flist.append(words[2])
    for mail in flist:
        fdict[mail] = fdict.get(mail,0) + 1
    print(fdict)
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

## the one below is one loop less
    
def wd():
    inp = input("Filename: ")
    fhand = open(inp)
    fdict = dict()
    start_time = time.time()
    for line in fhand:
        line = line.rstrip() #remove \n in the right
        if not line.startswith("From "):
            continue #finds line starting with From and then find next one
        words = line.split() #create list of words in the line
        weekday = words[2]
        fdict[weekday] = fdict.get(weekday,0) + 1
    print(fdict)
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: How big are the files, i.e. how many lines are in them? You probably won't notice any difference in execution speed unless you go into the millions of lines.

Comment: You are not closing your file handles properly. General rule: Don't use `open()` without a `with` block. Instead of `fhand = open(inp)`, write `with open(inp) as fhand:`, the `with` block will take care of closing the file.

Comment: Other remark: Python comes with a built-in timing module called `timeit` that's more useful for performance assessments. Usage e.g. https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-timeit-measure/.

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly because the **overhead of the loop iteration is negligible compared to the work done in each iteration**. This should be especially true here due to a file being read which is a generally slow operation (string manipulations too but not as much). Here is a famous picture about the overall speed of many operations:

[image]

Note that you forgot to close the file `fhand`.